# Jackson deserialization list class

Tags: java, jackson, json-deserialization

There is a json with a sheet as a nested class:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "phoneList": {
        "phone": [
            {
                "number": 32323232,
                "code": 555
            },
            {
                "number": 4343423432,
                "code": 555
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The following DTO class is suitable for this json:

```
class Response {

  String name;
  PhoneList phoneList;

  static class PhoneList {

    List<Phone> phone = new ArrayList<>();

    static class Phone {

      String number;
      Integer code;
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible somehow not to create a PhoneList class, but to create a sheet directly?

```
class Response {

  String name;
  List<Phone> phoneList = new ArrayList<>();

  static class Phone {
    String number;
    Integer code;
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider declaring your internal classes as `static`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add below method and it is gonna work like a charm (of course if you make those DTOs proper Jacson pojos (i.e. default constructor + setters/getter)

```
@JsonProperty("phoneList")
private void mapPhones(Map<String, List<Phone>> phoneList) {
  this.phoneList = phoneList.get("phone");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! A good option, but I use an immutable class as a dto (I forgot to specify it).

Comment: then you may use it in constructor, the syntax exactly the same

`public Response (@JsonProperty("name) name, @JsonProperty("phoneList")  Map<String, List<Phone>> phoneList) {
   this.name = name;
   this.phoneList = phoneList.get("phone")
}`

Comment: @wuttke if you find my answer helpful please mark is as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create that directly. Take a look at below code :

1. `Response` Class

```java
class Response {

    String name;
    List<Phone> phoneList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Response() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Phone> getPhoneList() {
        return phoneList;
    }

    public void setPhoneList(List<Phone> phoneList) {
        this.phoneList = phoneList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Response{" + "name=" + name + ", phoneList=" + phoneList + '}';
    }

    class Phone {

        String number;
        Integer code;

        public String getNumber() {
            return number;
        }

        public void setNumber(String number) {
            this.number = number;
        }

        public Phone() {
        }

        public Integer getCode() {
            return code;
        }

        public void setCode(Integer code) {
            this.code = code;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Phone{" + "number=" + number + ", code=" + code + '}';
        }
    }
}
```

2. `Main` Class

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    Response response = new Response();

    response.setName("test");

    Response.Phone phone = response.new Phone();
    phone.setNumber("32323232");
    phone.setCode(555);
    response.phoneList.add(phone);

    phone = response.new Phone();
    phone.setNumber("4343423432");
    phone.setCode(555);
    response.phoneList.add(phone);

    System.out.println(response.toString());

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(response));
}
```